# What is the font in the TV series "Masters of Sex"?

Tags: font-identification, tv-series

I was wondering if anyone knows which font is used in the titles of the TV series "Masters of Sex". I have come across this sans serif font before, almost always in a 60's office setting.
It looks like some sort of Futura spin-off (?) and I particularly like the lowered middle bar of the capital 'E'.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Masters of Sex logo]

Comment: Ahh.. I thought you were going to ask about the logo: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kHtpI.jpg It shows a good, and rare, use of negative space for a tv series masthead

Comment: It's the same font as hbo's girls!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be [Neutraface Medium, by House Industries](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/neutraface):

[image: Screenshot from House's web site]